# Area of $ M=\{[x,y] \in R^2; x (x^2+y^2) < x^2-y^2; x>0 \} $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I started out with expressing $y$ in terms of $x$:
$$
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\frac{x^2-x^3}{x+1}} <y
\end{equation}
$$

Now I integrate over $x \in (0,1)$ since I've graphed the above expression.
$$
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{x^2-x^3}{x+1}}dx = 1-\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{equation}
$$

...and the answer is supposed to be twice as much. Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: Your expression for $y$ should be:$$\sqrt{\frac{x^2-x^3}{x+1}} < |y|.$$ So when you consider the -ve root also, you will get double of what you got now, matching the correct answer.